# I need help making a map with jupyterlab + pygmt +others

Tags: maps, legend, jupyter-lab, shapefile, pygmt

I am currently working on a figure and I was recommended to use PyGMT.

However, I have been facing challenges in generating the legend for my plot.

The data provided to me is in an unconventional format, and I had to adjust it, resulting in the need to work with shapefiles instead of simple .txt data.

Despite writing the code along with the assistance of ChatGPT 4, I am still stuck on generating the legend.

Here is the code that plots everything correctly but lacks the legend generation:

```
import pygmt
import geopandas as gpd

# Create custom color palettes
# Ocean: from deep dark blue to light blue.
ocean_cpt_data = "... (omitted for brevity) ..."

with open("ocean_custom.cpt", "w") as ocpt:
    ocpt.write(ocean_cpt_data)

# Land: from medium gray to dark gray.
land_cpt_data = "... (omitted for brevity) ..."

with open("land_custom.cpt", "w") as lcpt:
    lcpt.write(land_cpt_data)

# Combine the custom color palettes
with open("combined.cpt", "w") as combined:
    with open("ocean_custom.cpt", "r") as ocean:
        for line in ocean:
            combined.write(line)
    with open("land_custom.cpt", "r") as land:
        for line in land:
            combined.write(line)

# Read the shapefile
contours = gpd.read_file("D:/.../1960_contour.shp")

# Main map figure
fig1 = pygmt.Figure()
main_region = [-75.2, -72, -40.5, -38.2]
fig1.basemap(region=main_region, projection="M6i", frame=True)
fig1.grdimage(grid=r"D:/.../gebco.nc", cmap="./combined.cpt")

# Plotting the trench with subduction symbols
trench_shapefile = r"D:/.../trench.shp" # Adjust the path to point to your shapefile
fig1.plot(data=trench_shapefile, pen="3", style="f1c/0.3c+r+t+o0.3c+p", fill="4")

# Plot contour lines and annotate with labels from shapefile's ELEV attribute
for line, value in zip(contours.geometry, contours['ELEV']):
    x, y = line.xy
    # Plot the contour
    fig1.plot(x=x, y=y, pen="0.5p")
    # Annotate the contour
    fig1.text(x=x[len(x)//2], y=y[len(y)//2], text=str(value), font="8p,Helvetica-Bold,black", offset="0/0.2c")

min_elevation = -5500
max_elevation = 4000

legend_entries = [
    "S 0.2i f0.5c/0.3c+r+t+o0.3c+p 0.25p 0.3i black 0.4i Trench",
    "S 0.2i - 0.25p black 0.3i Contours",
    f"G 0.2i - 1i ./combined.cpt 0.4i {min_elevation}/{max_elevation} Elevation (m)"
]

# Create a temporary file to store the legend specifications
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, mode="w", suffix=".txt") as legend_file:
    for entry in legend_entries:
        legend_file.write(entry + "\n")
    legend_file_name = legend_file.name

# Add the legend to the figure
fig1.legend(position="JTR+jTR+o0.5i", box="+gwhite+p2p", spec=legend_file_name)

# Show the figure
fig1.show()    

# Inset figure (code omitted for brevity)
```

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or insights on how to generate the legend for this plot using PyGMT.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to help here. The posted code example is not a working example as it is not complete and no input data are provided. Are there any error or warning messages?

I tried to understand how the legend should look like, but the third entry remains unclear to me:

`f"G 0.2i - 1i ./combined.cpt 0.4i {min_elevation}/{max_elevation} Elevation (m)"`

I reduced your code example. The required external legend file "legend_file.txt" looks like:

```
# legend in GMT / PyGMT ready format

N 1
S 0.45c f+r+t 0.2i/-3/0.1i black 0.1p,black 0.4i Thrust
G 0.05c
S 0.45c - 0.3i black 1p,black 0.4i Contours
```

```py
import pygmt

main_region = [-75.2, -72, -40.5, -38.2]

# Main map figure
fig = pygmt.Figure()

fig.basemap(region=main_region, projection="M6i", frame=True)

# Plot trench
fig.plot(
    x=[-74, -73],  # Use some dummy data
    y=[-40, -39],
    pen="3p",
    style="f1c/0.3c+r+t+o0.3c+p",
    fill="black",
)

# Plot contour lines
fig.plot(
    x=[-74.5, -73],
    y=[-40.4, -38.3],
    pen="0.5p",
)

# Annotate the contour lines
fig.text(
    x=-74,
    y=-39.5,
    text="depth",
    font="8p,Helvetica-Bold,black",
    offset="0/0.2c",
)

# Add the legend to the figure
# Create legend file externally
fig.legend(position="JTR+jTR+o0.5i", box="+gwhite+p2p", spec="legend_file.txt")

# Show the figure
fig.show()

# Save figure
#fig.savefig(fname="add_legend_to_plot.png")
```

The code produces the figure shown below. Does this legend fit to your expectation for the first two entries of your desired legend?
[image]